# How to convert YUV_420_888 to BGR using opencv python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have three ndarray which is Y.shape(307200,) U.shape(153599,) V.shape(153599,). what is the efficient way to convert this to BGR using opencv python? Those array are in [YUV_420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YUV_420_888)
 format.

[my_image which is 640*640](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nws4Q.png)

My code is

```
Y= np.fromstring(Y, dtype=np.uint8)
U= np.fromstring(U, dtype=np.uint8)
V= np.fromstring(V, dtype=np.uint8)
Y= np.reshape(Y, (480,640))
U= np.reshape(U, (480,320))
V= np.reshape(V, (480,320))
YUV = np.append(Y,U)
YUV = np.append(YUV,V)
img = np.reshape(YUV,(960,640))
img = np.asarray(img, dtype = np.uint8)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer**

The information [here](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV21) tells me that an Android NV21 image is stored with all the Y (Luminance) values contiguously and sampled at the full resolution followed by the V and the U samples interleaved and stored at 1/4 the resolution (1/2 the height by 1/2 the width). I have created a dummy NV21 frame below and converted it into OpenCV BGR format and that confirms the layout and the way OpenCV interprets it too. All the code below works in order from top to bottom, so just remove the images and squidge all the lines up together to make a Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Define width and height of image
w,h = 640,480

# Create black-white gradient from top to bottom in Y channel
f = lambda i, j: int((i*256)/h)
Y = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (h,w)).astype(np.uint8) 
# DEBUG
cv2.imwrite('Y.jpg',Y)
```

That gives Y:

[image]

```
# Dimensions of subsampled U and V
UVwidth, UVheight = w//2, h//2

# U is a black-white gradient from left to right
f = lambda i, j: int((j*256)/UVwidth)
U = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (UVheight,UVwidth)).astype(np.uint8)  
# DEBUG 
cv2.imwrite('U.jpg',U)
```

That gives U:

[image]

```
# V is a white-black gradient from left to right
V = U[:,::-1] 
# DEBUG 
cv2.imwrite('V.jpg',V)
```

That gives V:

[image]

```
# Interleave U and V, V first NV21, U first for NV12
U = np.ravel(U)
V = np.ravel(V)
UV = np.empty((U.size+V.size), dtype=np.uint8)
UV[0::2] = V
UV[1::2] = U

# Lay out Y plane, followed by UV
YUV = np.append(Y,UV).reshape((3*h)//2,w)

BGR = cv2.cvtColor(YUV.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21)
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',BGR)
```

Which gives this. Hopefully you can see how that is the correct RGB representation of the individual Y, U, and V components.

[image]

So, in summary, I believe a 2x2 image in NV21 image is stored with interleaved VU, like this:

```
Y Y Y Y V U V U
```

and a 2x2 NV12 image is stored with interleaved UV, like this:

```
Y Y Y Y U V U V
```

and a YUV420 image (Raspberry Pi) is stored fully planar:

```
Y Y Y Y U U V V
```

**Original Answer**

I don't have your data to test with and your question is missing some details, but I see no-one is answering you after 5 hours, so I'll try and get you started... no-one said answers have to be complete.

Firstly, I guess from your `Y.shape(307200)` that your image is 640x480 pixels, correct?

Secondly, your `U.shape(153599)` and `V.shape(153599)` look incorrect - they should be exactly half the `Y.shape` since they are sampled down at a rate of 2:1.

Once you have got that sorted out, I think you need to take your `Y` array and append the `U` array, then the `V` array so you have one single contiguous array. You then need to pass that to `cvtColor()` with the code `cv2.CV_YUV2BGR_NV21`.

You may need to reshape your array before appending, something like `im = Y.reshape(480,640)`.

I know when you use the C++ interface to OpenCV, you must set the height of the image to 1.5x the actual height (whilst leaving the width unchanged) - so you may need to try that too.

I can never remember all the constants OpenCV provides for image opening modes (like `IMREAD_ANYDEPTH`, `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`) and for `cvtColor()`, so here's a handy way of finding them. I start `ipython` and if am looking for the Android NV21 constants, I do:

```
import cv2

[i for i in dir(cv2) if 'NV21' in i]                                                                                                                       
Out[29]: 
['COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV21',
 'COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21',
 'COLOR_YUV2GRAY_NV21',
 'COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21',
 'COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21']
```

So the constant you need is probably `COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21`

The same technique works for parameters to `imread()`:

```
items=[i for i in dir(cv2) if i.startswith('IMREAD')]                                                                                                                                                          

In [22]: items                                                                                                                                                      

['IMREAD_ANYCOLOR',
 'IMREAD_ANYDEPTH',
 'IMREAD_COLOR',
 'IMREAD_GRAYSCALE',
 'IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION',
 'IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL',
 'IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2',
 'IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_4',
 'IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_8',
 'IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2',
 'IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4',
 'IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_8',
 'IMREAD_UNCHANGED']
```

Comment: Sorry, I said it was untested and incomplete :-) The one you want is `COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21` - the one I had was the C++ version. I have updated the answer.

Comment: The error message means the image you passed into `cvtColor()` was either not an even number of pixels wide, or the height of the image was not a multiple of 3 - this relates to the 1.5x Height I mentioned, 1.5 being 3/2.

Comment: My code,

`img = np.reshape(YUV,(960,640))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21)` where 960,640 are 1.5x but I still get same error :( .  Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, it's hard to read. Rather, click `edit` under your original question and update it there - also add in your code to create the `YUV` array. I have to go out for the rest of the day but will stop by when I get a moment. Sorry I can't be my normal, more helpful, self on this at the moment.

Comment: Now I get image which I posted in question, which I expect to be (640*480) but I get (640*640), any suggestions??

Comment: I have been looking at this some more this morning but am confused myself. The Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV says that the U and V are subsampled by a factor of 2 in X and Y, so you should have 1/4 as many U samples as Y samples, but you have half. Likewise with V. Note that in Numpy, images are created and accessed as H,W rather than the normal W,H.

Comment: Camera_Image 
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/lib/camera_image.dart which says image format is YUV420 and I get Y ,u=y/2,v=y/2 .

Comment: Finally I got it .. thanks a lot for your answers ,it helped me a lot

Comment: @satz Would you mind sharing how you got this to work? I am struggling with the same issue.