# Converting RGB image to YUV420 planar format

Tags: python, libyuv

I am interested to understand conversion of RGB image to YUV420 planar format, specifically in Python.
Any pointers/links would be helpful.

Found a library "libyuv" from Google but this is in C++. I tried looking at it, but I am a beginner in C++.

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571803/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53471006/2836621

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert YUV\_420\_888 to BGR using opencv python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566713/how-to-convert-yuv-420-888-to-bgr-using-opencv-python)

Comment: I was looking for the conversion other way around. Thanks for your comments.